# "Can I X before Y resolves?" Many questions, one answer in A:NR

Tags: discussion

Would it improve the quality of the site to replace specific instances of this question with a very thorough explanation of paid ability timing in Android: Netrunner?

Examples [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23019/android-netrunner-may-i-trash-a-card-before-i-am-forced-to-discard) and [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/25682/trashing-two-birds-with-one-stone/25683#25683) both boil down to whether a player can trigger some paid ability before the effects of some other ability are resolved. The answer is usually "no", although it might be awesome to have an extensive answer giving examples where it won't work, as well as examples (e.g. Jackson blowing up an iceless server during the paid ability window before the run is successful) where it will work to interesting effect. We can even cross-link the hilarious meme from [this thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/17509934#17509934). As a bonus, we would have a reference point for just pointing future analogous questions to the superthread, and closing them as dupes.

Inspired by [a similar discussion](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1340/do-green-mms-have-summoning-sickness-or-many-questions-one-answer) about M:tG.

Comment: I've seen a mild amount of success proposing a more general title in the comments while suggesting that the specific case being asked about is not exceptional. If the author generalizes the question, then that is a success, and a canonical question is born *naturally*. If the author explains why the specific case is exceptional, then that is also a success.

Answer (score 3):

The question you're describing has not been asked yet in its full form, so you're free to do so. If you know the answer, even better. I think canonical questions are a great way to keep the site clean.

Of course, as Rainbolt states in his comment, if there is a way to expand on an existing question that would be one less duplicate to sort out. This becomes more difficult the longer a question exists, as specific answers will likely have been upvoted before you generalize the question.

Here's a great take on canonical Q&A from meta: [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/where-to-post-a-canonical-answer-when-its-not-in-response-to-a-specific-quest).

Comment: Ooh, thanks for the link, that's super useful.